# How to push mandatory notification with flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

So I have this app in flutter, in which there are two `textfeilds`.
One is 'Reminder title' and another is the description/message.

[image]

Now what I want is that to push a notification with the information from the `textfeilds`.
And I want the notification to be there until I mark it as done from the app.
Now I have been using [flutter_local_notifications](http://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications). But I have been getting errors by following their documentations. Actually no notification came after pressing the button.

### I need help with some code to achieve the following purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use [awesome_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications) for this purpose, in case `firebase` and `flutter_local_notification` becomes problematic.

Basically you have to initialize a `channel`:

```
import 'package:awesome_notifications/awesome_notifications.dart';

AwesomeNotifications().initialize(
  // set the icon to null if you want to use the default app icon
  'resource://drawable/res_app_icon',
  [
    NotificationChannel(
        channelGroupKey: 'basic_channel_group',
        channelKey: 'basic_channel',
        channelName: 'Basic notifications',
        channelDescription: 'Notification channel for basic tests',
        defaultColor: Color(0xFF9D50DD),
        ledColor: Colors.white)
  ],
  // Channel groups are only visual and are not required
  channelGroups: [
    NotificationChannelGroup(
        channelGroupkey: 'basic_channel_group',
        channelGroupName: 'Basic group')
  ],
  debug: true
);
```

and then create desired notification by =>

```
AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
  content: NotificationContent(
      id: 10,
      channelKey: 'basic_channel',
      title: 'Simple Notification',
      body: 'Simple body'
  )
);
```

Read their documentation for more information.
And [here is their video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JAq9fVn3X7U).